# How to distinguish between reference and value in golang

Tags: go, struct, reference

```
package main

type A struct {
    Num int
}

func getA() A {
    return A{Num: 10}
}

func main() {
    if getA().Num == 10 {
        // getA().Num = 20 // why not working
        myA := getA()
        myA.Num = 20
    }
}
```

why "getA().Num = 20" line do not working?

I'm don't know the difference between

```
myA := getA()
myA.Num = 20
```

and

```
//getA().Num = 20 // why not working
```

I think it just two line and one line...

I'm more familiar with Java.

What I need to know to understand it?

I expected the code working correctly....

Comment: The Tour of Go explains pointers and this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Tweak your function declaration like this, and it will work as you're expecting:

```golang
func getA() *A {
    return &A{Num: 10}
}
```

What has changed is that `getA` returns a *pointer* to a value of type `A`.

In Java, class data types are always used as references (like a pointer), except the language doesn't use an explicit notation like this. So, writing Go code to use pointer types like `*A` is similar to what you're used to in Java.

The part that may confuse you is that Java doesn't have a direct equivalent for Go's *non-pointer* types, like the plain `A` in your Go code. In Java, you can only declare a `class` type, which *always* acts as a reference.